# MAP TWILIO PHONE NUMBERS TO USER

Tags: twilio

how can i map a twilio phone no with user phone no in php.Can u give me the example or code.

previous work i have done.
basically i am working on masked number integration 
1.purchase no from twilio 
1. create twmil app and webhook url which is php page 
2. and configre with purchased no

when user call the twilio no that call forwared to my desicre no

my php file code

```
    <pre>

header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
include_once("DataBase.php");
include_once("../function.php");

$file = 'calls.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= "call data == ".json_decode($_REQUEST)."\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);



$CallData = $DataBase->Select_Row(array("to_email","id","from_email"), "calls_twilio","isCalled!='1' order by id desc");
$to_email=$CallData->to_email;
$id=$CallData->id;
$from_email=$CallData->from_email;

$userFrom = $DataBase->Select_Row(array("txtb_contactno"), "tbluser", "txtb_email='$from_email'");
$userTo = $DataBase->Select_Row(array("txtb_contactno"), "tbluser", "txtb_email='$to_email'");

$from_No = $userFrom->txtb_contactno;
$toNo = $userTo->txtb_contactno;
$SenderNo=$Global_SETTINGS_ARRAY["twilio_call_from_no"];
mysql_query("update calls_twilio set isCalled='1' where id = '$id'");

<Response>
    <Pause length="1"/>
    <Dial callerId="<?=$SenderNo?>"><?=$toNo?></Dial>
</Response>
    </pre>
```

and i wanna send some extra paramter when user call that no to my webhook url 
note i dont wanna use voip call
but i wanna number masking system like uber

thanks

Comment: Could you try explaining your question a bit fuller and include any work that you've done already to try to attempt this? Thanks

Comment: question update please check

Comment: Do you know your users' phone numbers already?

Comment: yes, i know about

Comment: but it also save in database

Comment: I can't answer this right now as the question is on hold, but you are able to access the caller's number from `$_REQUEST["FROM"]`. You should then use that number to look up your user from the database. There is a [PHP/Laravel tutorial in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/php/laravel) that might help.